# Group operation on $M_2(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to determine whether there is a nontrivial homomorphism between $M_2(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$ and $Aut(\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z})$ but I don't understand what the underlying group operation is on $M_2(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$, i.e. if I multiply the matrices as it is done in $M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ what do the multiplication and addition mean (respectively).

Comment: In $Aut(\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z})$, are those the automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z}$ as an additive group or a multiplicative group?

Comment: It's the additive one.

Answer (score 1):

The addition is done component wise, in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ : 
$$\begin{pmatrix} A_{1,1} & A_{1,2} \\ 
A_{2,1} & A_{2,2}\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} B_{1,1} & B_{1,2} \\ 
B_{2,1} & B_{2,2}\end{pmatrix} := 
\begin{pmatrix} A_{1,1} + B_{1,1} \mod 3 & A_{1,2} + B_{1,2} \mod 3 \\ 
A_{2,1} + B_{2,1} \mod 3 & A_{2,2} + B_{2,2} \mod 3\end{pmatrix}$$

The multiplication is defined as usual, but in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ :
$$A \cdot B := C \textrm{ where }\forall 1\leqslant i,j \leqslant 2, \, C_{i,j}:=\Big(\sum_{k=1}^2 A_{i,k}B_{k,j} \Big) \mod 3$$

Answer (score 0):

As to the stated problem, which is to determine whether there is a non-trivial homomorphism $Aut(\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z}) \mapsto M_2(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$. 
You can answer by the negative as follow :

- The **order** of the group $M_2(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$ is $3^4=81$ since for $A \in M_2(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$ we have 3 choices for each $A_{i,j}$.
- The order of the group $Aut(\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z})$ is $8$.

Now let $\phi : Aut(\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z}) \mapsto M_2(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$ be an homomorphism. Let $a \in Aut(\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z})$ with $a\neq Id$. Assume for contradiction that $\phi$ is non-trivial : there's $a\in Aut(\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z})$ such that $\phi(a)\neq 0$.

The order $m$ of $a$ divides $8$ and is different from 1.
The order $n$ of $\phi(a)$ divides $9$ and is different from 1. Hence $m,n$ are coprime.

By the identity of Bezout, there are $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $kx + ly = 1$. $x$ and $y$ are of opposite sign. Assume for simplicity that $y<0$ and $x>0$. We get
$$\underbrace{\phi(a^{kx})}_{=0} = \phi(a^{l|y|+1})=\underbrace{(l|y|)\phi(a)}_{=0} + \phi(a)$$
Whence $\phi(a)=0$, a contradiction!